# characterize the order units of $C_b(X)$ and $C_0(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

1. Characterize the order units of $C_b(X)$. Does $C_b(X)$ always have an order unit?
2. Characterize the order units of $C_0(X)$ if $X$ is locally compact. Does $C_0(X)$ always have an order unit?

I think that all constant functions are order unit for both $C_b(X)$ and $C_0(X)$, but I do not know that they always have an order unit or not.

please help me.

Comment: Do you know that you can vote for questions, answers and even accept answers to yor question? Just click the chemark under votes count

Answer (score 0):

1. If $f\in C_b(X)$, i.e. $f:X\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and bounded, and if $c> 0$ is a constant, then using $\lambda_f:=\displaystyle\frac{\sup_X |f|}{c}$, we indeed have $f\le \lambda_f\cdot c$. 
   This shows that $C_b(X)$ does have order units, and that positive constant functions are such. 
   Now, try to prove that the ordered units are exactly the bounded functions $f$ with $\inf f>0$.
2. The nonzero constant functions now are typically *not contained* in $C_0(X)\ $ (unless $X$ itself is compact, whence $C_0(X)=C_b(X)=C(X)$). 
   Now suppose that $X$ is not compact, and a continuous function $e\in C_0(X)$ with compact support $K$ wants to be an order unit. Then choose [show there is] a  nonzero function $f\ge 0$ with compact support in $X\setminus K$, then with no $\lambda>0$ will we get $f\le \lambda\cdot e$ as the right hand side is zero on the whole support of $f$.